# Getting "Closes Issue #n" on unrelated issue somehow (or so i think)

Tags: gitlab

I am getting "Closes Issue #27" on an unrelated issue somehow and i am not sure why this #27 is being shown as closing (it shouldn't be related at all - i checked #27 and no issues are linked to it)

In the description of the merge request i tagged issue #33 and that's what I would expect to close.

(I am new to using GitLab, apologies....)

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Thank you for you help!

Comment: I figured it out... silly me... i forgot the Closes #27 in the commit message

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... silly me... i forgot the Closes #27 in the commit message